# In Clojure is there an easy way to convert between list types?

Tags: clojure

I am often finding myself using a lazy list when I want a vector, and vice versa. Also, sometimes I have a vector of maps, when I really wanted a set of maps. Are there any helper functions to help me to convert between these types?

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Let's not forget that trusty old `into` lets you take anything `seq`able (list, vector, map, set, sorted-map) and an empty container you want filled, and puts it `into` it.

```
(into [] '(1 2 3 4)) ==> [1 2 3 4]         "have a lazy list and want a vector"
(into #{} [1 2 3 4]) ==> #{1 2 3 4}        "have a vector and want a set"
(into {} #{[1 2] [3 4]}) ==> {3 4, 1 2}    "have a set of vectors want a map"
(into #{} [{1 2} {3 4}]) ==> #{{1 2} {3 4}} "have a vector of maps want a set of maps"
```

`into` is a wrapper around `conj`, which is the base abstraction for inserting new entries appropriately into a collection based on the type of the collection. The principle that makes this flow so nicely is that Clojure is build on **composable abstractions**, in this case `into` on top of `conj` on top of collection and `seq`.

The above examples would still compose well if the recipient was being passed in at run time: because the underlying abstractions (`seq` and `conj`) are implemented for all the collections (and many of Java's collections also), so the higher abstractions don't need to worry about lots of special data-related corner cases.

Comment: +1 for into... worth noting that it also works with non-empty original containers as well (i.e. when you want to add to a collection)

Comment: It's also worth noting that because `into` uses `conj`, doing `(into '() some-seq)` will yield a list that's the *reverse* of some-seq, because `conj` conses onto lists.

Comment: It's worth noting that `into` utilizes transients (for most seq types) for better performance characteristics than most other conversion means.

Comment: And it now works with transducers, which didn't exist at the time this answer was written (I don't know if transients did either) (This answer is old enough to enrol in kindergarten)

Answer (score 34):

`vec`, `set` and generally `into` are your friends to easily "convert" to another collection type.

How do you want to transform a vector of maps into a map of maps? You need a key, can you provide use with sample input/expected output?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a set of maps.. I have amended the question now

Answer (score 24):

For vectors there is the `vec` function

```
user=> (vec '(1 2 3))
[1 2 3]
```

For lazy sequences there is the `lazy-seq` function

```
user=> (lazy-seq [1 2 3])
(1 2 3)
```

For converting into sets, there is the `set` function

```
user=> (set [{:a :b, :c :d} {:a :b} {:a :b}])
#{{:a :b} {:a :b, :c :d}}
```

Comment: When you have something non-lazy calling `lazy-seq` instead of `seq` just adds a useless indirection. If really you want to return something non-nil even fore empty collectiosn thene there's `sequence`. `lazy-seq` is somewhat of a low-level construct.

Answer (score 15):

One more answer for converting from a list to a map (for the sake of completeness) - from [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojure/M49y0877Ors):

```
(apply hash-map '(1 2 3 4))
;=>{1 2, 3 4}
```

Answer (score 9):

To convert a vector to a list you can also use `for`, like this:

```
=> (for [i [1 2 3 4]] i)
(1 2 3 4)
```

When you don't want to manipulate the data, just use `seq` on the vector:

```
=> (seq [1 2 3])
(1 2 3)
```

Comment: Instead of `for` you could just do `(map identity [1 2 3 4])`

Answer (score 8):

There is no need to *convert* a vector to a list. Clojure will treat a vector as it would treat a list - as a sequence - when a sequence is required. For example,

```
user=> (cons 0 [1 2 3])
(0 1 2 3)
```

If you need to make sure that the vector is being treated as a sequence, wrap it in `seq`:

```
user=> (conj [1 2 3] 0) ; treated as a vector
[1 2 3 0]

user=> (conj (seq [1 2 3]) 0) ; treated as a sequence
(0 1 2 3)
```

---

If you have a vector of maps, and you want a set of maps, it doesn't matter that the vector holds maps. You just convert the vector to a set as usual:

```
user=> (set [{:a 1, :b 2} {"three" 3, "four" 4}])
#{{:a 1, :b 2} {"four" 4, "three" 3}}
```