# How to convert map to a sequence?

Tags: clojure

Answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088803/in-clojure-is-there-an-easy-way-to-convert-between-list-types/20642291#20642291) explain how to convert maps, sequences, etc. to various sequences and collections, but do not say how to convert a map to a sequence of alternating keys and values.  Here is one way:

```
(apply concat {:a 1 :b 2})
=> (:b 2 :a 1)
```

Some alternatives that one might naively think would produce the same result, don't, including passing the map to `vec`, `vector`, `seq`, `sequence`, `into []`, `into ()`, and `flatten`.  (Sometimes it's easier to try it than to think it through.)

Is there anything simpler than `apply concat`?

Comment: what does "simpler" mean for you? and why do you want more simpler solution? `apply concat` seems very simple solution at least for me.

Comment: `apply concat` is fine, @ymonad.  I don't need a simpler solution.  It's common to discover that there's a single Clojure function that does something simple and obvious (converting a map to a sequence, in this case) that one didn't realize would have that effect.  It's helpful to know those options.  (I suppose, also, that in general I feel that using `apply` except when you have a collection argument that would normally be the `rest` of a list with a function in its `first`, is, I don't know ..., aesthetically unpleasant.)

Comment: For eager conversion to a vector of alternating keys and values: `(reduce into {:a 1 :b 2})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do

```
(mapcat identity {:a 1 :b 2})
```

or

```
(mapcat seq {:a 1 :b 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

As @noisesmith gently hints below, the following answer is seductive but *wrong*: left as a warning to other unwary souls! Counterexample:

```
((comp flatten seq) {[1 2] [3 4], 5 [6 7]})
; (1 2 3 4 5 6 7)
```

---

`(comp flatten seq)` does the job:

```
((comp flatten seq) {1 2, 3 4})
; (1 2 3 4)
```

But `flatten` on its own doesn't:

```
(flatten {1 2, 3 4})
; ()
```

I'm surprised it doesn't work, and in that case it should return `nil`, not `()`.

None of the others you mention: `vec`, `vector` ... , does anything to the individual *[key value]* pairs that the map presents itself as a sequence of.

Comment: `flatten` is almost always the wrong thing to use, it destroys the structure of your keys and values (if they have any)

Comment: @noisesmith I agree. OP's solution - essentially `(partial apply concat)` - is accurate and credible.