# Flatten Nested Map into List with Depth-First Search Ordering

Tags: clojure, nested-map

In clojure, how can I turn a nested map like this:

```
{"1" {"1.1" {"1.1.1" {}
             "1.1.2" {}}
      "1.2" {}}
 "2" {"2.1" {}
      "2.2" {}
      "2.3" {}}}
```

Into this:

```
("1" "1.1" "1.1.1" "1.1.2" "1.2" "2" "2.1" "2.2" "2.3")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a straightforward iterative solution (using `loop` and `recur`):

```clj
(defn flatten-map [m]
  (loop [in m out []]
    (if-let [[[k v] & ts] (seq in)]
      (recur (concat v ts)
             (conj out k))
      out)))
```

And a "fancy" one (using [`tree-seq` function](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/tree-seq))

```clj
(defn flatten-map [m]
  (->> [nil m]
       (tree-seq sequential? second)
       (drop 1)
       (map first)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive solution:

```
(defn flatten-map [m]
  (flatten
    (for [[k v] m]
      (cons k (flatten-map v)))))
```

Comment: It's a very bad idea to use `flatten` here. You should use something non-recursive instead, e.g. `apply concat`.

Comment: Can you please explain why? (Not disagreeing with you)

Comment: Recursion is not inherently bad. Does this particular case incur significant overhead or otherwise harm performance? If so, I can see how loop/recur would help out.

Comment: I don't like `flatten` because it adds unnecessary complexity since you only need a one-level flattening here.

Comment: Though, recursion is always slower than iteration and could cause a stack overflow. But recursive solutions are usually much simpler and easier to understand.

Comment: `flatten` may also produce an unwanted result. For example, try flattening `{1 {[1 1] {} [1 2] {}}}` with your function. Instead of expected `[1 [1 1] [1 2]]` your function will produce a flattened `[1 1 1 1 2]`.

Comment: You may also want to look at this question: [Clojure: Why is flatten “the wrong thing to use”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25182904/1202461).

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that you should use `flatten` only when you want to flatten some **nested** data structure of unknown depth. But there are much better ways to perform one-level flattening.