# How can I convert a map into a vector?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

If I have a map that looks like:

```
{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
```

how can I convert it into a vector like:

```
[:a 1 :b 2 :c 3]
```

Comment: Would `[:c 3 :a 1 :b 2]` also be a valid result (with the keys visited in a different order)?

Comment: Yes, since maps make no promise on the order of the `MapEntry` items (i.e. key-value pairs).  The key is that `(apply hash-map (t/keyvals m1))` is always idempotent.

Answer (score 11):

Combining `into` with a `cat`ting transducer is quite concise:

```
(into [] cat {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
;;=> [:a 1 :b 2 :c 3]
```

Comment: Why the `reverse` in ClojureScript? If it is really necessary it needs explaining …

Comment: @glts That is a good point! This edit was suggested by Marcellinus but I don't know why it is needed. I will remove it again until it can be explained.

Comment: To maintain the order of the returned, it ordering in ClojureScript using `(into [] ...)` works slightly different.

Comment: @Marcellinus Maps are an unordered data structure, so order should not be relevant in any case.

Comment: True, but the vector returned might need to be in which case the order is reversed if expressed as suggested in the solution above in cljs

Comment: I think it is best to assume that the order is not important and that `[:b 2 :a 1 :c 3]` is a perfectly valid result as well even if it is not stated in the question because as @glts points out, usually maps are not ordered in Clojure (although there is also `sorted-map` in Clojure). And if you want a sorted output, I believe it would be more robust to use `sort` than `reverse` to accomplish that because it doesn't make any assumptions about the type of map that we flatten.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `reduce-kv`:

```
(defn kv-vec [m] (reduce-kv conj [] m))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `mapcat` and `vec` to achieve it:

```
(vec (mapcat identity {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}))
;; => [:a 1 :b 2 :c 3]
```

Comment: Better use `identity` instead of `#'identity`.

Comment: @gits it is because I come from common lisp. But isn't it also not wrong in clojure to use `#'` in front of function names to designate that it is a function?

Comment: I know it is not a necessity. But it is not wrong - and I have seen quite frequently this being used... Or am I wrong in the way how I see it?

Comment: `#'identity` returns the var `clojure.core/identity` rather than the contained function. Var implements `IFn` by assuming the contained value is a function and invoking it which is why your example works, but it's more common to use `identity` so the var is derefed first before being passed to `mapcat`.

Comment: @Lee thanks for the explanation. I will adapt my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple function for this purpose

```
(ns demo.core
  (:require 
    [schema.core :as s]
    [tupelo.schema :as tsk]))

(s/defn keyvals :- [s/Any]
  "For any map m, returns the (alternating) keys & values of m as a vector, suitable for reconstructing m via
   (apply hash-map (keyvals m)). (keyvals {:a 1 :b 2} => [:a 1 :b 2] "
  [m :- tsk/Map]
  (reduce into [] (seq m)))
```

with unit test:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test))

(dotest
  (let [m1 {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
        m2 {:a 1 :b 2 :c [3 4]}]
    (is= [:a 1 :b 2 :c 3]   (t/keyvals m1))
    (is= m1 (apply hash-map (t/keyvals m1)))
    (is= m2 (apply hash-map (t/keyvals m2)))))
```

As the unit test shows, `keyvals` is the inverse of `(apply hashmap ...)` and can be used for deconstructing a map. It can be useful when calling functions that require ***keyword args***.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest using `flatten` and `vec`

```
(vec (flatten (vec {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})))
```

On the repl it will look like this:

```
user=> (vec (flatten (vec {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})))
[:a 1 :b 2 :c 3]
```

Comment: `flatten` is never the right answer. Try this on an input map like `{:x [1 2], :y [3 4]}` and you'll be in for a nasty surprise.

Comment: I don't agree. We have to check what the OP wants in the case of `{:x [1 2], :y [3 4]}`. Maybe they want `[:x 1 2 :y 3 4]`, in which case this solution works for them. Or maybe they never have nesting of collections.

Comment: Alan asked this question for the explicit purpose of providing his own answer (based on a recent closed question with a similar premise but badly asked). He provided one that works (modulo his insistence on using his tupelo library), with the identity that `(= m (apply hash-map (keyvals m)))`, and a test case your function fails. But in the grand scheme of things it doesn't matter what OP wants, it matters what they actually asked; Stack Overflow's job is to make it easy to find high-quality answers via search engines, so we want an answer that appeals to people who get here via Google.

Comment: I believe the answer I provided is useful to some and people who arrive here from Google may need this answer over the others. Here's a general use case: consider a tree using maps as in `{:a {:x :m} :b {:y :n} :c :z}`, the program may want a vector of all the nodes in the tree for any number of reasons. In this case, the result `[:a :x :m :b :y :n :c :z]` would be the correct result.

Comment: @amalloy, I see that you really don't like this answer using `flatten`. I'm beginning to think maybe you see something I don't... I really don't see why this is not a good answer and perhaps you are much  more savvy about Clojure and functional programming than me. Can you say precisely why `flatten` is "never the right answer" and why people that arrive here from a Google search should _not_ be using this solution _ever_? I think this would be helpful, not just to me and my education, but to anyone that arrives here from a Google search.

Comment: Stack Overflow comments aren't really the best place for an extended discussion. But flatten is just not in general a very well-behaved function: it sometimes looks good when you think of simple data (no nested collections), but falls apart when extended to nested collections. I never had a reason to use flatten in my 5 years of professional Clojure. Also, I can tell you didn't run the example you gave, because it does not in fact provide the result you say you would expect. Take that as one more piece of evidence that flatten is not a good function to recommend to newcomers.

Comment: But you could give a link to a blog post or something if you know of one.

Comment: For those interested, I did find a couple sources on the subject, but nothing with an authoritative explanation of when to use `flatten`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182904/clojure-why-is-flatten-the-wrong-thing-to-use
https://twitter.com/stuarthalloway/status/1100671127003766795
The best I got, paraphrased: use `flatten` when it does what you want, but know what it does before you make that decision and know the (possible) structure(s) of the input data.

Comment: Stuart Halloway surely counts as authoritative, if that's what you're looking for. I don't know Cognitect internals well enough to confidently call him Rich's right-hand-man, but he is somewhere up there. You can't find anyone authoritative recommending the time to call flatten because they don't recommend you call it. The only use of flatten I could find in Clojure itself is https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/4ef4b1e/test/clojure/test_clojure/java/io.clj#L109, a test where it surely would have been better to just use a vector instead of a map to begin with.