# Flattening different types of result

Tags: functional-programming, clojure, clojurescript

i want result like this,
["abc" "def" "ghi"] or ("abc" "def" "ghi")

1. problem with conj is :

> cljs.user=> (conj ["IT","AB"] "MX" ["ad" "cd"])
>
> ["IT" "AB" "MX" ["ad" "cd"]]

2. problem with conj is :

> cljs.user=> (conj ["IT","AB"] "MX" ["ad" "cd"])
>
> ["IT" "AB" "MX" ["ad" "cd"]]

however, i have found a solution for it, but not sure if using flatten is safe or not

> ((comp vec flatten conj)  ["IT"] "MX")
>
> ["IT" "MX"]

does anyone know any predefined function just like conj or concat which i can use here

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
user=> ((comp flatten conj vector) ["IT","AB"] "MX" ["ad" "cd"])
("IT" "AB" "MX" "ad" "cd")
```

Comment: Hi yes i have tried this and its working fine as I mentioned in my question I'm not sure whether its safe to use flatten

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182904/clojure-why-is-flatten-the-wrong-thing-to-use) out.